# ADB not working after software update macOS Mojave

Tags: android, adb

ADB was working fine, but after installing updates, it stopped working.What might have been the issue. I have tried re-installing all platform-tools again, but it didn't work.It does not show any devices while using command `adb devices`.

Comment: Update to android or Mojave? Check to make sure developer setting did not get reset i.e. usb debugging, usb configuration.

Comment: I had Mojave already, it was some software updates for mojave. All the tools are in path, what might have been reset? What should I do now? @BoLawson

Answer (score 1):

It seems port 5037 was used by something else after update, 
I had help finding it using

```
netstat -anv | grep 5037
```

Its output was

```
tcp46      0      0  *.5037                 *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    303      0 0x0180 0x00000006
```

Then I killed it using `sudo kill -9 303`

And it fixed the issue.

Thanks to @Josh Bartels.